# Detect the user's locale automatically

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

My goal is to recognize the local user's browser and automatically set the language.

Then allow the user to change language and keep it on other pages.

At the time I set the routes in this way:

```
# homepage not localized: load the homepage with default language
index_not_localized:
   path:   /
   defaults:  { _controller: "AcmeSiteBundle:Default:index", _locale: %locale% }


acme_site:
   resource: "@AcmeSiteBundle/Controller/"
   type:     annotation
   prefix:   /{_locale}
   defaults:  { _locale: %locale% }
   requirements:
        _locale:  %route_locale_requirements%
```

When the user enters the page example.com without specifying the language in the local route is set by default, and the page there is a switcher that allows you to change the language:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     {% for locale in ['en', 'it'] %}
         <li>
             <a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_locale': locale}) }}">
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How do I do what I want?

I have to create a listener? I have put the local session?

I'm confused, I read several answers but have not found a clear answer!

Comment: Something like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, but responds only to a part of the problem.
How do I automatically detect the user's locale?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, even if you implemented detection by IP because English speaker could open your site from Russia. Just make language switcher.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways, but both of them don't gave you 100% guarantee to detect locale and detect it right.

The first is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` variable. It's gotten via HTTP Headers and can even doesn't exist.

The second is to use 3rd-side services to detect country by IP address and then compare country name to some local table of countries and their locales. For example:

http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=127.0.0.1

For more information and comments look at this question: [Simplest way to detect client locale in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297542/simplest-way-to-detect-client-locale-in-php)

And the final point is to integrate locale detection into the symfony2 project. This is the simplest part. You just need to use `kernel.request` event listner. Everything is perfectly explained (with examples) here: [Symfony 2.1 set locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276756/symfony-2-1-set-locale)