# symfony2 locale translations catalogue

Tags: symfony, translation, locale

I experiment with Symfony2 Translation and I am very close to finish something, but I don't know what to do in this step.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14331838/1162217

```
<?php

namespace TB\LanguageBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
                return;
        }

        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            $request->setLocale("fr");
        }
    }

    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

That works great, the locale really changes, but I have a problem with catalogues. The `default_locale` is *en*, but when I change the locale via `setLocale` to *fr*, the result in page looks like this:

```
Fr home
Another fr already translated sentence
i.did.not.translate.this.sentence.already.but.i.need.en.fallback.to.it (instead i want -> i am the english fallback sentence)
```

In other words the sentences which are not translated already are outputed as translation keys. Can I somehow achieve that instead of these bad translation keys the output would be the sentence from "fallback language" ?

My `app/config.yml` look like (`%locale%` is "en" in `parameters.yml`):

```
translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution... "cache:clear" @Wouter J thx.

My face have covered with red color... but hopefully this will help someone.