# Symfony -- Twig's trans filter not picking up locale

Tags: symfony, localization, twig

I have verified that if I add the following line to my twig template, it outputs the desired locale:

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

However, the following is outputting in English:

```
{{ 'String'|trans }}
```

If I force the locale of the trans filter:

```
{{ 'String'|trans({}, 'messages', 'ja') }}
```

It outputs in the proper translation.  Note that I'm setting the locale using an eventListener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $locale = $request->cookies->get('_locale') ? $request->cookies->get('_locale') : $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->availableLanguages);

    $request->setLocale($locale);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer through [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale):

> Setting the locale using `$request->setLocale()` in the controller is too late to affect the translator.
>
> Either set the locale
>
> - Via a **Listener** (like above)
> - Via the **URL** (see next)
> - Or call `setLocale()` directly on the **Translator Service**.

I ended up fixing it by **changing the priority of the service**, like the accepted answer in this thread:  [Symfony 2.1 set locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276756/symfony-2-1-set-locale?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Mabey a late reply but I was facing the same problem, after a bit of reading i found a better solution. You can use the `trans function` instead of the `trans filter` which seems to be a cleaner solution.

```
{% trans from "your-trans-domain" into app.user.locale %} trans.key {% endtrans %}
```

See symfony docs:

[Docs v2.7 for translations](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/translation.html)