# Symfony2 login event listener and security.interactive_login event never triggered using FOSUser

Tags: security, events, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add a Symfony2 login event listener, the goal is to set a database-stored locale if the user is logged, on each request, and to fallback to a default one of there is no user logged.
I use FOSUserBundle, and I'm trying to get the security.interactive_login event to work. I find a lot of code over the internet like this one: http://dev.dbl-a.com/symfony-2-0/how-to-add-a-symfony2-login-event-listener/

I have my own child bundle of the FOSUserBundle and this implementation in services.yml:

```
my_user.security.interactive_login_listener:
        class: My\UserBundle\EventListener\UserListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }

my_user.security.kernel_request_listener:
        class: My\UserBundle\EventListener\UserListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser }
```

Problem is, the security.interactive_login event is never triggered, even when logging, even when logged. On the contrary, my setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser is always trigered.
Every code sample I found seems to work fluenty, what's wrong with my app?

Comment: What is the branch version of symfony2 and the version of the FOSUserBundle ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out too, and did more or less the same work around:
There is no problem indeed, but there is some kind of redirection after login, so the profiler never show the actual request who trigger the interactive login listener.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\FilterControllerEvent,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

class LocaleListener {

    protected $container;
    protected $availableLocales;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container $container, $availableLocales) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->availableLocales = $availableLocales;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale = $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->availableLocales);
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
        if( is_object( $token ) ) {
            $user = $token->getUser();
            if ($user instanceof BaseUser) {
                $locale = $user->getLocale();
            }
        }

        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
 }
```

In services.yml:

```
user.locales.kernel_request_listener:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: [ @service_container, [ 'en', 'fr', 'ru' ] ]
        tags: [{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: -255 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem here. But the problem is not that event is not triggered. The problem is that after redirecting, the request locale is lost. With the help from this link:

[Changing locale with symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146282/changing-locale-with-symfony-2-1)

(And based on [this](https://gist.github.com/1670163))

I figured out how to solve it. In the UserListener:

```
class UserListener
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession($session) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }    

    public function setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ('undefined' == $request->getLocale()) {
            if($locale = $request->getSession()->get('_locale')) {
                $request->setLocale($locale);
            } else {
                $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if ($locale = $user->getLocale()) {
//            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($user->getLocale());
            $this->session->set('_locale', $locale);
        }
    }
}
```

In services.yml, you should declare:

```
your_listener_name:
    class: ...\UserBundle\EventListener\UserListener
    calls:
        - [ setSession, ['@session'] ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }
```

Hope this helps.